# Cannot connect to the wireless access point: association timed out

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I am trying to extend my wireless coverage [using a VersaLink 327W as a wireless range extender and AP](https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r19210450-Using-a-VersaLink-327W-as-a-wireless-range-extender-and-AP).

I followed the instructions:

1. Disabled DSL.
2. Enabled wireless access with a WEP key (the device does not support WPA and WPA2).
3. Disabled DHCP.
4. Set IP address to `192.168.7.2` (because the main router to which this one is to be connected via ethernet is `192.168.7.1`).

Alas, I cannot connect to the device via WiFi from a linux box:

```
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: authenticated0
kernel: [run timestamp] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
kernel: [run timestamp] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
kernel: [run timestamp] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: associate with <<6*hex>> (try 1/3)
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: associate with <<6*hex>> (try 2/3)
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: associate with <<6*hex>> (try 3/3)
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: association with <<6*hex>> timed out
```

I.e., *authentication* works, but **association** (whatever that is) does not.

This is unlikely to be a problem with linux as I cannot connect from a
Mac and an Android phone either.

So, what can I do now?

Thanks.

PS. Additional information requested by @Twisty:

I set `localhost` IP in `/etc/hosts`, then

```
# service network-manager restart
```

and observe this:

```
wpa_supplicant[pid]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with <<6*hex>> (SSID='sgv' freq=2437 MHz)
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: authenticate with <<6*hex>>
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: send auth to <<6*hex>> (try 1/3)
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nm-applet[pid]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
nm-applet[pid]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: authenticated
kernel: [run timestamp] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: Connection to AP <<6*hex>> lost
nm-applet[pid]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
kernel: [run timestamp] wlan0: aborting authentication with <<6*hex>> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
NetworkManager[pid]: <warn>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
NetworkManager[pid]: <warn>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'sgv'
NetworkManager[pid]: <info>  [wall timestamp] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
```

note that `ifconfig` seems to ignore my setting.

Comment: What happens if you assign your client device a static IP address such as `192.168.7.3`, then try to connect to the wireless? Also, once you get this working, don't use WEP. No no no no no.

Comment: @Twisty: even if this works (I will try it tonight), this is not a solution because I cannot use it with Mac, Android &c.  Also, WEP is the only authentication method supported by the device.

Comment: Sorry, I am suggesting this as a troubleshooting step meant to determine if there are problems with DHCP. I understand this isn't a desired long-term configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58153/discussion-between-twisty-and-sds).

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar issue today. What fixed it for me was changing a configuration of the NetworkManager:

1. Edit file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`(the location may vary, depending on your distro)
2. Add the following lines to that file:

   ```
   [device]
   wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
   ```
3. Reboot the NetworkManager service: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: First, this is the setting I already have on linux. Second, I also need to be able to connect to the wireless device from Mac and Android devices.